# Is it possible to disable Google Analytics cookies from server?

Tags: google-analytics

I need to know if it is possible to disable Google Analytics cookies from a web server, and if this can cause the web to malfunction

Is that a client has asked me to deactivate Google Analytics cookies on the server for a data privacy issue, and my question is if it can be done and how, and if it is done if it harms the functionalities of the web

Comment: I would be impressed if you could break the web by disabling cookies.

Comment: Are you saying you want to keep analytics but not have it place cookies?  I doubt you can do that, the javascript added to a site pulls in the code from google's servers.  I am sure they have some built in security to stop cookies being tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is unclear.

You can disable Google analytics code in your web site and it will stop Google analytics tracking through your website. (I expect this is what the client wants). The only thing disabling this will break is google tracking - and conceivably affect SEO.

You can't disable a Google Analytics cookie from a server (unless you are Google) as this data never goes to your server.

Comment: Google analytics stores first-party cookies under your own domain name.  Those do get sent to your server.  They are set by the analytics JavaScript and I would imagine that it is possible to write JavaScript that deletes them as soon as they are set.